# Card is not abstract error?

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance, abstract-class

I created a program that is suppose to extend a given class. However, I'm getting an error stating that the program is not abstract, when it shouldn't be abstract either way.

**Here is the question I am trying to solve:**

A standard deck of playing cards consists of 52 cards. Each card has a rank  and a suit. You will create a class called Card that will simulate cards from a standard deck of cards. Your class will extend the AbstractCard class (provided).

The ordering of the cards in a standard deck (as defined for this assignment) is first specified by the suit and then by rank if the suits are the same.

The suits and ranks are ordered as follows:
suits: The suits will be ordered
diamonds  < clubs < hearts < spades

ranks: The ranks will be ordered
2 < 3 < · · · < 9 < 10 < Jack < Queen < King < Ace

A Joker card is a special card that is “greater” than any other card in the deck (any two jokers are equal to each other). A joker has no suit (”None” from AbstractCard.SUITS).

Again, the overall ordering for non-joker cards is specified by suit first and then rank; for example, all club cards are “less than” all heart cards. Two cards with the same rank and suit are considered equal.

Write a Java class called Card that extends the provided Card class. Your class must have two constructors:

public Card(String rank, String suit)

purpose: creates a card with given rank and suit

preconditions: suit must be a string found in Cards.SUITS rank must be a string found in Cards.RANKS

Note: If the rank is AbstractCard.RANKS[15] then any valid suit from AbstractCard.SUITS can be given but the card’s suit will be set to AbstractCard.SUITS[4]

public Card(int rank, String suit)

*purpose:* creates a card with the given rank and suit

*preconditions:* suit must be a string found in Cards.SUITS

Note: as with the other constructor, if a joker is created, any valid suit can be passed but the card’s suit will be set to AbstractCard.SUITS[4]

Note that the case of strings is important here. The input strings must be exactly the same as those found in AbstractCard.SUITS or AbstractCard.RANKS.

The specification for the three abstract methods in the AbstractCard class are given by:

public int getRank()

*Purpose:* Get the current card’s rank as an integer

*Output:* the rank of the card

joker -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, ..., 10 -> 10

jack -> 11, queen -> 12, king -> 13, ace -> 14

public String getRankString()

*Purpose:* Get the current card’s rank as a string

Returns the cards’s rank as one of the strings in Card.RANKS (whichever corresponds to the card)

public String getSuit()

*Purpose:* Get the current card’s suit

Returns the card’s suit as one of the strings in Card.SUITS (whichever corresponds to the card)

**Abstract Code :**

```
public abstract class AbstractCard implements Comparable<AbstractCard>{

 /* handy arrays for ranks and suits    */
 /* do NOT change these                 */
 public final static String[] RANKS = { "None", "None", 
   "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
   "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace", "Joker"};

 public final static String[] SUITS = { "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts",         "Spades", "None"};



 /** the numerical representation of the rank of the current card
  *  <p>
  * ranks have the numerical values
  *  2 = 2, 3 = 3, ..., 10 = 10
  *  Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13, Ace = 14
  * Joker = 1 
  * @return the numerical rank of this card 
  */
 public abstract int getRank();



 /** the string representation of the rank of the current card 
  *
  * @return the string representation of the rank of this card 
  *         (must be a string from Card.RANKS) 
  */
 public abstract String getRankString();


 /** the suit of the current card 
  *
  * @return the suit of this card (must be a string from Card.SUITS) 
  */
 public abstract String getSuit();



 @Override
 public final String toString(){
 // outputs a string representation of a card object
 int r = getRank();
 if( r >= 2 && r <= 14 ){
   return r + getSuit().substring(0,1);
 }else if (r == 1){
   return "J";
 }
 return "invalid card";
 }

}
```

**MY CODE:**

```
public class Card extends AbstractCard { 

  public Card(String rank,String suit) {

this.strRank = rank;

this.suit = suit;

setIntRank();

}

public Card(int rank,String suit) {

this.intRank = rank;

this.suit = suit;

setStringRank();

}

private void setIntRank() {

String temp = strRank.toLowerCase();

switch(temp) {

case "jack":

intRank = 11;

break;

case "queen":

intRank = 12;

break;

case "king":

intRank = 13;

break;

case "ace":

intRank = 14;

break;

default:

intRank = Integer.parseInt(strRank);

break;

}

}

private void setStringRank() {

switch(intRank) {

case 11:

strRank="Jack";

break;

case 12:

strRank="Queen";

break;

case 13:

strRank="King";

break;

case 14:

strRank="Ace";

break;

default:

strRank = ""+intRank;

break;

}

}

public int getRank() {

return intRank;
}
public String getRankString() {

return strRank;

}
public String getSuit() {

return suit;

}

}
```

Comment: I don't think `Card` implements the `compare` method from `Comparable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the functionality defined by the `Comparable` `interface`, which `AbstractCard` promises to conform to.

This means adding the method `compareTo` to either `AbstractCard` (probably preferable) or `Card`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(AbstractCard o) {
    // Your implementation
}
```

IMHO, I'd suggest starting with a `interface`, which would describe the functionality a `Card` would promise to provide.  I'd then use a `abstract` class to implement the core or common functionality (like `toString` and `compareTo`) and would then make a concrete implementation. The main reason for this, as it decouples the code to a much greater degree and allows the implementation to be changed without affecting the code that relies on the `interface` - but that's just me ;)

Comment: We're not allowed to change AbstractCard, would it make a huge difference if the method was added to Card?

Comment: @MuthuShank All that means is that you would have to reimplement it in any other class (besides `Card`) that extends `AbstractCard`, which may be a waste of time.  If you're not planning on writing any other such class, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @MuthuShank That's not really how abstraction should work, but if your up for the work to implement in EVERY class that extends from `AbstractCard` then you can do it, but, it could cause issues as it's a point of potential errors (as one implementation of `compareTo` might be different from another - unintentionally). Is there anything wrong with it? No, would I do it? No

Comment: Is it possible to get any help on what I should do? Completely confused with what I have to do to make this work so that it follows the requirements of the question.

Comment: @MuthuShank You MUST implement the `compareTo` method.  It needs to make determinations about weather the current object is greater to, less then or equal to the supplied object

Comment: @MuthuShank The requirements say, "The ordering of the cards in a standard deck (as defined for this assignment) is first specified by the suit and then by rank if the suits are the same."  So you need to write a `compareTo` that compares the suits, returns a result if they're different, and then compares the ranks if the suits are the same.

Comment: @ajb And? You seem to understand the requirements, you just need to write the code. You also need to read the [JavaDocs on `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to understand the expected return result.  This is a very common API. You need to make some attempt at solving this before anyone will help you, as you need to pass the course, not us - sorry

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, I don't need to write the code, the OP does. :)  Typo, I presume...

Comment: @ajb Lack of sleep more like ;P